# MST in a Graph of Coordinates

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

Which algorithms are good for computing cost in a MST of coordinates.

Comment: Only to store the edge (weight) information you'll need an order of 1e10 memory...

Comment: How is this graph represented?

Comment: Do the edge weights have some structure that you haven't told us about?

Comment: The graph is connected and weights are the distances between two coordinates. Like if (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are two coordinates, the weight of the edge connecting these two coordinates is (|x2 - x1| + |y2 - y1|).

Answer (score 1):

You refer in a comment to Manhattan distance as weight of edges. This problem is known as Manhattan minimum spanning tree. You can find how to construct it in a Topcoder community [post](https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/line-sweep-algorithms/) (at the very end).